# Irreducible components of this variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can you give me a clue of how to obtain the irreducible components of $V(y^2 − x^4,x^2 −2x^3 − x^2y + 2xy + y2 − y)$?

Comment: Possible type:  should $y2$ be $y^2$?

Answer (score 1):

First factor $y^2-x^4$ into two parabolas. Then the variety is a subvariety of these two. So the components will be points. (unless the second polynomial contain one of the parabolas which I havent checked)

Comment: This is going out on a limb, but I would guess that Rebecca has no problems with factoring. Rather, it is the concept that irreducible components of an affine variety correspond to factoring the defining equations which is giving her trouble. Perhaps your answer could address this as well.